# Initializer does not override a designed initializer from its superclass error in swift

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors

When I opened my project that already had swift classes on Xcode 6.3.2, it shows an error. I would like you to help me in order to solve this problem. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might be trying to use a compiler that is not compatible with your current swift syntax. Make sure your swift code is up to date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got a few different errors here; let's deal with them one at at time.

**Overriding a convenience initializer**
Per the Swift documentation from Apple:

> if you write a subclass initializer that matches a superclass convenience initializer, that superclass convenience initializer can never be called directly by your subclass, as per the rules described above in Initializer Delegation for Class Types. Therefore, your subclass is not (strictly speaking) providing an override of the superclass initializer. As a result, you do not write the override modifier when providing a matching implementation of a superclass convenience initializer.

So ditch the `override` keyword and you should be set. Speaking of sets…

**Upgraded interfaces for touch methods in Swift 1.2**
[Paul Solt](http://iphonedev.tv/blog/?author=50c11a79e4b03a359fe4d4b2) of iphonedev.tv covers this in [Swift 1.2 fixes and breaks a few things: you should be excited!](http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2015/2/9/swift-12-fixes-and-breaks-a-few-things-you-should-be-excited), and I recommend you read the whole post (not to mention the release notes that he links to), but the short of it is that NSSet has been replaced by a native Set type. As he says:

> Fix: You'll need to update your method signature (i.e.: the entire first line) to the following:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
```

He also notes that there's no an anyObject() method on Set, so you're going to have to work around that with the interface provided.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

## Swift

> You do not need the the `override` keyword in a `convenience` initializer, because **you cannot** override such initializer.

**Fix**: remove the `override` keyword.

```
convenience init() {
    self.init(frame: CGRectZero)
}
```

Furthermore, either `init()` **is** a designated initializer (in STBTableViewIndex) or it is not.  If it is, replace `convenience override init()` by `required init()`, which implies `override` in the first place.

Comment: Not working.

convenience override init() {
        self.init()
        self.notificationCenter.delegate = self
    }